# splice is not removing the first index from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular6, array-splice

I have two arrays of objects and I want to compare the objects of the first array to the ones of the second array. If they match, I use the `splice` to remove the object from the second array.

I have the following code

```
existing.forEach((existingitem, existingindex, existingfeatures) => {     
  (newdatafeat.features).forEach((newitem, newindex, newfeatures) => { 
    console.log('existing index-name --- new index-name', existingindex ,' - ',existingitem.values_.name,' - ',newindex,' - ',newitem.properties.name,'-----');
    if (existingitem.values_.id == newitem.properties.id &&  existingitem.values_.cat == newitem.properties.cat){              
      console.log(' index to remove - ', newindex); (newdatafeat.features).splice(newindex,1);              
    } 
  })
});
```

So, If `existing` is

```
var existing= [
  { info: true, values_:{id:1, cat:true, name : "John"} }, 
  { info : true, values_:{id:2, cat:false, name : "Alice"} }  
];
```

and `newdatafeat.features` is

```
var newdatafeat= {
   status:scanned,
   features : [  { info: true, properties:{id:1, cat:true, name : "Mike"} }, 
    {  info : false, properties:{id:22, cat:false,name : "Jenny"} }  ]
};
```

Then, Mike from `newdatafeat.features` should be removed.

The error is that every item of the `newdatafeat.features` array with index 0 is not removed. In the loop, I can see `index to remove - 0`, but Mike is never removed. I know, because if I `console.log` the `newdatafeat.features` after the loops, Mike is there

This is inside an angular6 code.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, "Mike" has `id:1, cat:true`, like "John" from `existing` . The id and cat match, so Mike must be removed. I am only comparing id and cat, not the names. Check the `if` statement again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to clean up some code, but it looks like yours is working fine.  It identified one element to be removed, called slice and it was gone.

```js
var existing = [{
    info: true,
    values_: {
      id: 1,
      cat: true,
      name: "John"
    }
  },
  {
    info: true,
    values_: {
      id: 2,
      cat: false,
      name: "Alice"
    }
  }
];


var newdata = {
  status: "scanned",
  features: [
    {
      info: true,
      properties: {
        id: 1,
        cat: true,
        name: "Mike"
      }
    },
    {
      info: false,
      properties: {
        id: 22,
        cat: false,
        name: "Jenny"
      }
    }
  ]
};




existing.forEach(
  (existingitem, existingindex, existingfeatures) => {
    (newdata.features).forEach((newitem, newindex, newfeatures) => {
      console.log('existing index-name --- new index-name', existingindex, ' - ', existingitem.values_.name, ' - ', newindex, ' - ', newitem.properties.name, '-----');

      if (existingitem.values_.id == newitem.properties.id && existingitem.values_.cat == newitem.properties.cat) {
        console.log(' index to remove - ', newindex);
        (newdata.features).splice(newindex, 1);
      }
    })
  });
  
 console.log(newdata.features);
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the bag in my code? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: i renamed newdatafeat to newdata.  And i updated `var newdata` from an Array to an object.

Comment: thanks for the remarks on the `newdatafeat` object. I edited my question. However my problem remains. I dont know if it's caused by angular or openlayers, I dont know how to even proceed to debug. Thanks

Comment: @codebot So does running the snippet in this answer produce the correct result, or not?

Comment: Why did i get down voted?  I fixed the sample and it works.  If you changed your question give me a chance to edit it.  Dont downvote me.

Comment: @Nix I got downvoted too, idk why, and I found the actual problem :)

Answer (score -1):

The main problem here is that you are iterating an array in a loop, but you are *removing* items from that array in the same loop.  So the index will often be off, and the wrong element or no element will be removed.  It can be hard to reproduce with simple examples, but here ya go:

```js
function removeVowels(letters) {
  letters.forEach((element, index, arr) => {
    if ('aeiou'.indexOf(element) > -1) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
}

var myArray = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
removeVowels(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
// works great!

var myArray = ['a','e','c','d','b'];
removeVowels(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
// wtf!
```

A simple way to approach this problem is to handle the looping manually, and change the index manually if you DO remove an element.

```js
function removeVowels(letters) {
  for (var i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if ('aeiou'.indexOf(letters[i]) > -1) {
      letters.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}

var myArray = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
removeVowels(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
// works great!

var myArray = ['a','e','c','d','b'];
removeVowels(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
// hurray!
```